# How to highlight user control based on keyboard focus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have designed my form like this ini WPF:

[image: usercontrol wpf]

So how to make highlight background of `Halaman12b` in each column with different color when I have focused keyboard in one of my textbox in `Halaman12`?

I used my user control of `Hal 12` like this:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="Susenas2015.Content.KOR.Halaman12"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:kor="clr-namespace:Susenas2015.Content.KOR"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1200" d:DesignWidth="1500">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <kor:Halaman12a Width="300"></kor:Halaman12a>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListART5_1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <kor:Halaman12b DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So what I want like highlighting particular column when I get focus in one of my TextBox in `Halaman12`?

Thanks

Comment: Specifically when `TextBox` has focus or any control within has focus?

Comment: any control within has focus.. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `kor:Halaman12b` is `UserControl` which does not set `Background` to local value you can change background of control depending on [`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin(v=vs.110).aspx)

```xml
<kor:Halaman12b DataContext="{Binding}">
    <kor:Halaman12b.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type kor:Halaman12b}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </kor:Halaman12b.Style>
</kor:Halaman12b>
```

Comment: I will add one thing here. Put this in your user control resources, so that you don't have to copy this code for textboxes,

Comment: Thanks.. I have put in my user control resources.. :D